Ontology as graph
I am a beginner in ontologies, so I apologize for the basic question. Some people told me that ontologies are graphs, which makes sense to me regarding algorithms; others told me that ontologies are  "in the format of a graph" and that graphs are not ontologies because they do not contain formal semantics. Could anyone explain this relationship between graphs and ontologies? Could anyone give me a reference?

I'd interpret that as meaning something similar to: English is a language but not all languages are English

some ontologies can be represented as graphs (i.e., OWL ontologies have RDF graph representations, with minor limitations - some axioms do not have a unique graph representations), but one can question whether focusing on that representation is useful. Example: an ontology consisting of one axiom like this: "owl:Thing subclass of some R", meaning everything has an R property, has a simple graph representation, but any individual added does not have a link to this axiom, in any OWL syntax. That semantic aspect isn't captured by graphs.


others told me that ontologies are "in the format of a graph" and that graphs are not ontologies because they do not contain formal semantics.

By this logic, nothing is a graph, so I think that this logic proves too much. Also, I'm not sure what "in the format of a graph" means in this context.
As far as a graph goes, a graph is simply a collection of vertices and edges connecting them. They don't have any intrinsic meaning, so using them to describe ontologies, social networks, dependencies, or whatever else they're used for is just a matter of interpretation.
If you want to be really strict about terminology, I suppose that it would probably be more accurate to say that things like ontologies, social networks, etc. are represented by graphs rather than they are graphs. This seems like semantics to me, though, so I think it's fine to say that they are graphs.
